# MongoDB exchange Out Body is null, using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache, mongodb, apache-camel, routes

I am trying to save some data in MongoDB using apache Camel.
Following is my code

```
from("direct:saveData")
.process(dataSaveRequestProcessor)
.streamCaching()
.to("mongodb:emailDB?database=myDB&collection=myData&operation=save&writeConcern=safe&writeResultAsHeader=true")                
.process(dataSaveResponseProcessor);
```

Now issue is in MongoDB record is saved, but it is not returned back to my Response Processor. I need _id that is generated in MongoDB to pass to another Route.

Following is System.out in Response Processor

```
===============> OUT BODY : null
===============> OUT BODY HEADER: {}
===============> IN BODY : { "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017" , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 22 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}
===============> IN BODY HEADER : {CamelMongoWriteResult={ "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017" , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 22 , "err" :  null  ,
```

"ok" : 1.0}, CamelMongoDbLastError={ "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017" , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 22 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}}

Can anybody pointed out where I am making mistake. Why there is not _id in ***exchange.getIN().getBody()***

Thank you in Advance

Comment: This question was also posted to the Camel mailing list, where Raul answered it - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/MongoDB-exchange-Out-Body-is-null-using-Apache-Camel-td5742888.html

Comment: he mentioned that I need to use writeResultAsHeader, that I am already using. Do you have any other solutions. Now I am stuck here.