# Why is Camel MongoDB component changing the body inspite of writeResultAsHeader=true

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel

I am using Camel 2.10.4 to save a document to Mongo 2.10.1. As part of the Mongo endpoint configuration, I am specifying the

```
writeResultAsHeader=true
```

so that my message body is unchanged and the result is stored in the exchange header under "CamelMongoWriteResult". The problem is that the endpoint is saving it to the header but is updating the body as well.

My route configuration is as follows:

```
RouteBuilder routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(camelContext) {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("direct://testMongoSave")
      .routeId("testMongoSave")
      .log("Before persist headers = ${headers}")
      .log("Before persist body = ${body}")
      .to("mongodb:mongo?database=events&collection=TEST&writeResultAsHeader=true&operation=insert&dynamicity=true")
      .process(new PrintingProcessor())
      .log("After persist headers = ${headers}")
      .log("After persist bosy = ${body}");
 }

 class PrintingProcessor implements Processor {
   @Override
   public void process(Exchange exchange) {
     LOGGER.warn("In Header {}", exchange.getIn().getHeader(MongoDbConstants.WRITERESULT));
     LOGGER.warn("In Body {}", exchange.getIn().getBody());
     LOGGER.warn("Out Body {}", exchange.hasOut() ? exchange.getOut().getBody() : "No OUT");
   }
 }
```

};

Log output

```
10:57:14 [INFO ]SpringCamelContext: Apache Camel 2.10.4 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.281 seconds
10:57:14 [INFO ]testMongoSave: Before persist headers = {breadcrumbId=ID-saket-kumar-lmuk-local-34130-1385722634064-0-1}
10:57:14 [INFO ]testMongoSave: Before persist body = { "name" : "Saket"}
10:57:14 [WARN ]CamelMongoDBTest: In Header { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 154 , "waited" : 37 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}
10:57:14 [WARN ]CamelMongoDBTest: In Body { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 154 , "waited" : 37 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}
10:57:14 [WARN ]CamelMongoDBTest: Out Body No OUT
10:57:14 [INFO ]testMongoSave: After persist headers = {CamelMongoWriteResult={ "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 154 , "waited" : 37 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}, breadcrumbId=ID-saket-kumar-lmuk-local-34130-1385722634064-0-1}
10:57:14 [INFO ]testMongoSave: After persist body = { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 154 , "waited" : 37 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}
```

I have looked at the Camel [MongoDbProducer](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=camel.git;a=blob;f=components/camel-mongodb/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/mongodb/MongoDbProducer.java;h=64b181066dfbfb06186a6d7a8c6d0b2ef265ffa2;hb=67f562cf00a4ac54b7367094e877d42e82cac72a) source and I think there may be a bug (last line) where we are updating the body without checking the writeResultAsHeader flag.

```
// we always return the WriteResult, because whether the getLastError was called or not, the user will have the means to call it or 
// obtain the cached CommandResult
processAndTransferWriteResult(result, exchange);
resultMessage.setBody(result);
```

I see another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864970/mongodb-exchange-out-body-is-null-using-apache-camel) but the problem there is slightly different

Has anyone encountered the same issue? Or is my usage incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The WriteResult in the option WriteResultAsHeader is a com.mongodb.WriteResult that's returned by Mongo on write operations. It's not referring to the writing the results of an operation (such as find). You could save the body pre mongo call and then restore is post I guess.